# do I download the image twice or only once if I set up a new Glide download inside onResource ready?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I have two image views overlap on top each other. the base is blurry image view, and top of it is just normal image view. we expect the user to upload an image with ratio 1:1, but if it is not 1:1 then the blurry image view will appear and make it look slightly better.

[image]

the image source (`imagePath`) for both imageViews is the same. I use Firebase Storage, so the number of downloaded images will affect my billing. so basically I want to avoid to download the same image twice.

so for basic imageView, I use glide as usual. but for blurry image view. I call it inside `onResourceReady`. using the code below, do I download the image twice or only once ? especially the code inside `onResourceReady`, I am not sure if that re-download the image from server or use the image from cache.

here is the code I use

```
        val imagePath = "http://www.imagePathIsTheSame.com/photo.jpg"

        Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(imagePath)
            .error(R.drawable.eventempty)
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

                    recommendedEventViewHolder.blurryImageView.setImageDrawable(null)
                 

                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {


                    Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(imagePath)
                        .apply(bitmapTransform(BlurTransformation(25, 3))) // add blur effect
                        .into(recommendedEventViewHolder.blurryImageView)

                    return false
                }

            })
            .into(recommendedEventViewHolder.posterImageView)
```

I can use that `resource:Drawable` from `onResourceReady`, but it seems so slow. thats why I use the code above